# Unable to start the local development server of react app with npm start

Tags: npm, create-react-app

I am unable to start up the local React development server using `npm start` which I had no problem a few months before. I installed using `npx create-react-app`. My error log shows something like this:

```
> react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:621
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\dEBA\code\frontend\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss'
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:499:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:854:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dEBA\code\frontend\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parse.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dEBA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-29T14_58_06_913Z-debug.log
```

I have tried deleting **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** folder/file and running

`npm install -g npm@latest`

`npm install`

Still, the error seems to persist. Is there a solution to fix this?

My **package.json** file reads as:

```
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening because CRA's pre built packages are not supported on node version which you are using.

Either downgrade your react-scripts version or upgrade your node version.

downgrading would be improper, so I recommend you to use LTS version which is currently up to > 14.

[Reference](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) notes as below, that would be work.

> You’ll need to have Node 8.16.0 or Node 10.16.0 or later version on
> your local development machine